# location redirect to "sms:123454" does not work on page load

Tags: javascript, mobile, sms, uri, mobile-browser

Following is the code I have got for location redirect to SMS app when the user is on a mobile browser-

```
window.onload = function() {
    window.location ="sms:12345?body=" + encodeURIComponent("TEST");
}
```

This code works perfectly on JS fiddle when running on a mobile
JS Fiddle link -https://jsfiddle.net/netstarter/rwqyp2tn/1/

Comment: Try `document.onload`

Comment: If that doesn't help then try with `document.onready`

Comment: @TarunLalwani no it does not work with document.onload or document.onready

Comment: what happens when you manually type the same thing in a navigation bar? does it work

Comment: no, it does not work directly from navigation bar

Comment: Then why do you expect it to work through code?

Comment: @TarunLalwani because there might be a way to make it work.it works when used as <a href="SMS:12345?body=dwdwdwdwd">send</a>

Answer (score 2):

Easiest and appropriate way of doing this would be creating an hidden link and triggering it directly.

```js
window.onload = () => {
  let element = document.getElementById("hiddenAppLink");
  element && element.click();
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<a href='sms:12345?body=${encodeURIComponent("ITR")}' id="hiddenAppLink"></a>
</body>
</html>
```

You can also trigger it based on a condition by tracking the state if its closed or not in a variable instead bugging the user on every load (You can also use localStorage can't do it in fiddle => security violation). something like this.

```js
window.onload = () => {
  if(window.hideDialouge != true){
      let element = document.getElementById("hiddenAppLink");
      element && element.click();
      //Track if its alredy shown
      window.hideDialouge = true;
  }
};
```

```html
<html>
    <body>
    <a href='sms:12345?body=${encodeURIComponent("ITR")}' id="hiddenAppLink"></a>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: might be because of this ... https://www.androidpolice.com/2017/11/08/google-chrome-will-start-blocking-redirecting-ads/  .... Can't blame google though :).

Answer (score 1):

SMS URL seems to be only working when you are about to open new SMS URL. It fails to work when you manually enter the URL or use `window.location` redirect.

You can use two methods to achieve this:

1. Open hidden link.
2. Use `window.open` (This might ask user to allow popups on your page)

**1. Open hidden link.**

Create a hidden link and open it.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  let elem = document.getElementById("loadSMS");
  elem && elem.click();
}
```

```html
<a href="sms:1-111-1111?body=Blah" style="display:none" id="loadSMS">
</a>
```

**2. Use `window.open` instead of changing `window.location`**

```js
window.onload = function() {
  window.open("sms:1-111-1111?body=Blah");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had some sms challenges as well.
Here was my solution:

```
let a = document.createElement('a');
a.href = 'sms:?&body=Here is body message';
a.click();
```

Worked great on all my android and IOS devices!